# Mixed Layering of Parametric Plot in 3d pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

I am attempting to overlay 2d lines on a 3d surf plot in pgfplots, where the 2d lines are the minima of the function z=(1/2)* (x^2)*(y^2) as seen on the plot below. Is it possible to get the lines to be layered "on top" of the 3d plot when they are in view, and "behind" it when they are not? I have only managed to do this artificially by restricting the domains of the 2d lines to when they should be "in view", which is an imperfect solution since the square edges in the 2d plots don't match the curvature of the 3d plots, and it is very tedious.

The following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert={outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
  colormap/viridis,
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]

\begin{axis}[xmin=-2, xmax=2, ymin=-2, ymax=2, xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$]

\addplot3[
    samples = 50,
    samples y = 50,
    domain = -2:2,
    domain y = -2:2,
    surf,
    shader=interp,
    ]
    {0.5*x^2*y^2};
    \addlegendentry{$\frac{1}{2} x^2 y^2 $}

    \addplot3[line width = 2pt, color=red, variable=\t, samples y=0, domain=-2:2] ({0}, {t}, {0});
    \addlegendentry{$x=0$}
    
    \addplot3[line width = 2pt, color=orange, variable=\t, samples y=0, domain=-2:2] ({t}, {0}, {0});
    \addlegendentry{$y=0$}
\end{axis}            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces this:
[image: Incorrect layering of lines]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a workaround using a similar idea: draw the surface and the red line in two pieces, and order them. I'm creating some styles too, this way I avoid to repeat some code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert={outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset
{
  compat = newest,
  colormap/viridis,
  my line/.style={line width=2pt, line cap=rect, color=#1},
  my surf/.style=
  {
    samples = 50,
    samples y = 50,
    domain = -2:2,
    domain y = #1,
    surf,
    shader=interp,
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[xmin=-2, xmax=2, ymin=-2, ymax=2, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$]
\addplot3[my surf=-0.5:2]{0.5*x^2*y^2};
\addlegendentry{$\frac{1}{2} x^2 y^2 $}
\addplot3[my line=red]    coordinates {(0,-0.5,0) (0,2,0)};
\addlegendentry{$x=0$}
\addplot3[my line=orange] coordinates {(-2,0,0) (2,0,0)};
\addlegendentry{$y=0$}
\addplot3[my surf=-2:-0.5]{0.5*x^2*y^2};
\addplot3[my line=red]    coordinates {(0,-2,0) (0,-0.5,0)};
\end{axis}            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works a treat! Thanks for that. I assume this is probably the necessary approach on a case by case basis.